# WCF Authenitication/Authorization - Help Needed

Tags: wcf, authentication, authorization

I need help with WCF on how to properly setup authentication/authorization.  I would like to use as much out of the box as possible to get this done.

I am setting up a WCF 4.0 application service and I will have both 4.0 web and 4.0 silverlight clients connecting to the same service.  I would like for the client to call an authentication method on the service (which will verify username/password against database) and then return a token back to the client.  The client will then store this token and send it (transparently) with every subsequent service call.  On the service, this token will be verified with every call.  Also I will need to do some security checks (server side) during each operation call using the UserID, so that will maybe need to be included in the token.

I would like to get some client/server examples of how to accomplish this!  Thanks!

Comment: The scenario you're describing is probably the most "not-out-of-the-box" of all - you're basically doing everything (authentication, authorization) in your own custom code....

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using using a custom Secure Token Service.  My client calls the STS, authenticates and gets back a token which is stores.  Then I used a message inspector to insert the token into every outgoing wcf service call, and used a message inspector on the server side to intercept and validate every call by verifying the token.  This worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom username password validator with WSHttpBinding. This will give you an ability to validate the username password. However you cannot add data to the token that is shared once the auth happens.

This is a sessionful binding which means that a client has some associated state on the server. (this is not favorable for scaled out scenario with a load balancer in between since you might have to restablish the auth if the request goes to another server)

http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/WCF35SecurityGuidelinesNowAvailable.aspx

The authorization part is the tricky part since you can either declaritively specify Principal permission or with an imperative option. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx#AuthorizationOptionsWCF